# Как сообщить нейронной сети, что её ответ не верен, при этом не сообщая правильный ответ?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, pytorch

В стандартном обучении с учителем мы получаем ответ сети, потом сообщаем ей, какой ответ должен быть верным. Сеть в соответствии с полученными данными корректирует свои веса в направлении верного ответа.

```
 outputs = model(images)
 loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
 loss_list.append(loss.item())

 # Обратное распространение и оптимизатор
 optimizer.zero_grad()
 loss.backward()
 optimizer.step()
```

В labels мы указывает правильные ответы, и происходит обратное распределение ошибок. 
Вопрос в том можно ли и как указать сети, что её ответ не верный, при этом не сообщая правильного ответа? Верный ответ не известен. Можно только сказать есть ошибка или нет.

Comment: Не сообщая сети правильного ответа потому, что он нам неизвестен или по другой причине? Если так, то по какой? Чем более подробнее вы опишите свою задачу/вопрос тем больше вероятность получить полезный ответ ;)

Comment: потому что он не известен

Comment: OK, а по какому тогда критерию вы определяете, что ответ неверный? Что вообще должна делать эта НС? И откуда у вас тогда метки (labels) если ответ вам неизвестен?

Comment: lables я написал для примера обучения с учителем, в том и вопрос я не знаю что в нем должно быть в моем случае. Конкретно, я пишу бота для игры в сапер. То есть если открыл клетку - подорвался на мине. Ошибка, нужно корректировать. Не подорвался - отлично, делаем следующий ход. как-то так. Я полагаю использовать обучение с подкреплением, но как использовать очки подкрепления плохо представляю. Метод q-таблицы, применять не хочу, хочу чтобы обучение происходило после каждого хода.

Comment: хммм... т.е. карта с минами вам во время обучения неизвестна? может вам посмотреть в сторону эволюционных/генетических алгоритмов?

Comment: да доступны только цифры, указывающие на количество мин рядом. Я думал по поводу сверточных сетей, чтобы фильтр с размером окна 3x3 проходил и анализировал вероятность нахождения мины в клетке по доступным открытым клеткам.

Comment: да и хотелось бы чтобы после обучения бот умел решать игру с любым раскладом мин, а не только на котором обучали.

Comment: может можно как-то извратиться при помощи GAN (Generative Adversarial Network)...

Comment: нескольо сложновато для меня, Хотя можно рассмотреть и этот вариант.

Comment: может отсюда что-то полезное почерпнете: https://habr.com/ru/post/267047/

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю